# Подсветить строку и столбец (на javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Дана таблица умножения. Требуется подсветить столбец и строку, в которой находится подсвеченная ячейка (не используя CSS). По идее нужно использовать `parentElement`, и список его детей: `children`.

```js
    const table = document.createElement('table');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      const row = document.createElement('tr');
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        const col = document.createElement('td');
        let val = i * j;
        if (val === 0) {
          val = i || j;
        }
        col.innerHTML = val;
        row.appendChild(col);
      }
      table.appendChild(row);
    }
    
    document.body.appendChild(table);
    

    table.onmouseover = function(event) {
      let target = event.target;
      target.style.background = 'pink';
    };
    
    table.onmouseout = function(event) {
      let target = event.target;
      target.style.background = '';
    };
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
    
td {
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="table.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const table = document.createElement('table');

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    const col = document.createElement('td');
    let val = i * j;
    if (val === 0) {
      val = i || j;
    }
    col.innerHTML = val;
    row.appendChild(col);
  }
  table.appendChild(row);
}

document.body.appendChild(table);

const changeBg = (event, color) => {
  const target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName === 'TD') {
    target.style.background = color;
    //задаем фон родительскому элементу, т.е. строке, в которой находится ячейка
    target.parentNode.style.background = color;
    //получаем индекс ячейки в строке
    const index = event.srcElement.cellIndex;
    //задаем фон всем ячейкам с таким же индексом
    const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
    rows.forEach((row) => row.childNodes[index].style.background = color);
  }
}

table.onmouseover = (event) => changeBg(event, 'pink');
table.onmouseout = (event) => changeBg(event, '');
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const table = document.createElement('table');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      const row = document.createElement('tr');
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        const col = document.createElement('td');
        let val = i * j;
        if (val === 0) {
          val = i || j;
        }
        col.innerHTML = val;
        row.appendChild(col);
      }
      table.appendChild(row);
    }
    
    document.body.appendChild(table);
    

    table.onmouseover = function(event) {
      let target = event.target;
      target.style.background = 'pink';
      
      document.querySelectorAll(".highlight").forEach(
        item => item.classList.remove("highlight")
      );
      target.closest("tr").classList.add("highlight");
      target.closest("table").querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(
        row => row.cells[target.cellIndex].classList.add("highlight")
      );
    };
    
    table.onmouseout = function(event) {
      let target = event.target;
      target.style.background = '';
      
      document.querySelectorAll(".highlight").forEach(
        item => item.classList.remove("highlight")
      );
    };
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
    
td {
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

.highlight {
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="table.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```